# group generated by unipotents in arithmetic subgroup is finitely generated

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, lattices

Let $G$ be a semisimple algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-group and $\Gamma$ an arithmetic subgroup of $G$. In particular $\Gamma$ is finitely generated.

Denote by $\Gamma^{u}$ the set of unipotent elements in $\Gamma$. My main question is the following.

*Question 1.*: Is the group $\langle \Gamma^{u} \rangle$ generated by $\Gamma^{u}$ also finitely generated?

If the simple factors of $G$ are not of rank $1$, then for example the description of the normal subgroups by Margulis yields a positive answer. However, I am looking for a general answer which preferably doesn't use the latter.

Next, define also the group $N$ generated by the elements of $\Gamma^{u}$ lying in one of the factors of $G$.

*Question 2*: Is there any general results on the quotient group $\langle \Gamma^{u} \rangle/ N$?

If one defines all the above over $G$ instead of $\Gamma$ then such quotient was investigated and for example is always a finite group.

Assuming the following setup would in fact already suffice for me:

- $G \cong \prod_{i=1}^q GL_{n_i}(D_i)$ with $D_i$ a finite dimensional division $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra
- $\Gamma$ a subgroup of finite index in $\prod_{i=1}^q GL_{n_i}(\mathcal{O}_i)$ with $\mathcal{O}_i$ a ($\mathbb{Z}$-)order in $D_i$

Comment: For arithmetic Fuchsian groups this is in general false.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I could not come up with an example. Would it maybe be possible to give one or a reference please?

Comment: Take any arithmetic Fuchsian group with noncompact quotient of positive genus. Then your subgroup will be normal nontrivial of infinite index. Such a subgroup cannot be finitely generated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168913/normal-subgroups-of-free-groups-finitely-generated-implies-finite-index

Comment: Once more thanks for your useful comment!! I however still struggle to understand what this implies for the R-rank 1 SL_2(D)'s (i.e. D= Q, imaginary quadratic extension of Q or totally definite quaternion algebra over Q). For SL_2(Z) it follows from what you linked. But is there a general result for these groups saying that infinite index normal infinite subgroups are not f.g.?

Comment: Do you understand that in this case the group is not Fuchsian? It is the fundamental group of a 3-dimensional hyperbolic orbifold. The Fuchsian result likely extends to this case as well.

Comment: If I understood well PSL_2(Z) is an arithmetic Fuchsian group. Its principal congruence subgroups also and if its level is not a divisor of 4, then its unipotent elements generate an infinite index subgroup via the link you have added. 

 Besides I know that PSL_2(I_d), with I_d the ring of integers in Q(\sqrt{-d}), is a Kleinian group and the PSL_2(tdqa/Q) can be seen as standard arithmetic subgroups of SO(5,1). If the coefficient ring is Euclidean those groups are generated by unipotents so there question 1 is true. But I don't know about their congruence subgroups.

Comment: I am not sure about congruence-subgroups, but for arbitrary finite-index subgroups in lattices of $SO(3,1)$ the situation is the same as for Fuchsian groups: Each nonuniform lattice contains a finite-index subgroup such that unipotents generate an normal nontrivial subgroup such that the quotient group is not virtually cyclic. (This is a hard theorem, mostly due to Agol and Wise.) Another nontrivial (but not as hard) theorem ensures that such a subgroup cannot be finitely generated (mostly due to Stallings).

Comment: Thank you this info! Do you maybe have some reference ? (I did try to search but was not fruitful). I am very curious how the authors use the fact that the generators are unipotent...

Comment: There is no one reference covering this. I will write a proper answer once the strike is over (Ian Agol can also write one if he wishes).

Comment: Ok thank you. 

(I was not aware of the strike and have just read the full reasons for it and signed the petition. Hope the strike will work.)